# How to locate a string in memory with x64dbg

Tags: x64dbg

I opened a 32-bit program with x32dbg, I wrote something on a text box like this :

[image]

How can I find the piece of code that manipulates the string "Goku" ? I searched all string references but I didn't found it.

Comment: Really, do you want to crack the program or you just want to search for the string? I think this might be a kind of XY problem

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off looking for the message you get after you press enter. You'll have to find references to that string, then work backwards a little. Usually the "badboy" string will be almost immediately after the license check.

```
if (check_code() == 'valid')
    print("goodboy")
    continue
else
    print("badboy")
    exit
```

Comment: they display the "about" dialog if you enter a bad value and the software closes.

Comment: Ok... so find all the calls to the About box, there will probably only be 2.. one when it's selected in the menu, and one when you enter a bad code.